# Why I can't get an object with react router dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have googled everything for this error, but I haven't figure out the reason:

> invariant.js?409a:42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is
> invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
> class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of the Router.

Here is some partial code:

#### router

```js
// router
import Sandbox from "../component/sandbox/index.jsx";
import BinaryTree from "../component/sandbox/binaryTree";
import RandomSelect from "../component/sandbox/randomSelect";

import Index from "../component/index.tsx";
import game from "../component/game/game.jsx";
import JetFighter from "../component/game/jetFighter/index";

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
            <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
            <Route path="/game" component={game} />
            <Route path="/jetfighter" component={JetFighter} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/sandbox" component={Sandbox} />
            <Route path="/sandbox/binaryTree" component={BinaryTree} />
            <Route path="/sandbox/randomSelect" component={RandomSelect} />
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );

  }
}

export default Root;
```

#### index.js

```js
// index.js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";

import RootContainer from "../router/index.js";


const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render((
    <AppContainer>
      <RootContainer />
    </AppContainer>
  ), document.getElementById("app")
  );
};

render();

if (module.hot) {
  const index = require("../router/index").default;
  module.hot.accept(index, () => {
    render();
  });
}
```

#### pageage.json

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bundle-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "canvas": "^1.6.10",
    "canvg": "0.0.8",
    "d3": "^4.10.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "gsap": "^1.20.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "inquirer": "^5.2.0",
    "ip": "^1.1.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.19.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-d3-library": "^1.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.8",
    "webpack": "^4.8.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: @ArpitJain as usual, `BrrowserRouter` for serverRender, `HashRouter` for client Render. My url like this `http://192.168.41.69:8001/build/#/hello` so...

Comment: It's a package version issue. I have fixed it, when I re-install the package and update to lastest.

Comment: @Todd Mark Can you share any one of the component's code ??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use div between switch and route component.
Try below code:

```js
class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
            <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
            <Route path="/game" component={game} />
            <Route path="/jetfighter" component={JetFighter} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/sandbox" component={Sandbox} />
            <Route path="/sandbox/binaryTree" component={BinaryTree} />
            <Route path="/sandbox/randomSelect" component={RandomSelect} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** capitalise the name for the `game` component to `Game` (plus update the exported name in /game.jsx)

...

It seems like a silly difference, but
React components need to begin with a capital letter, here's a quote from the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component)

> ```
> Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.
> ```
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags. For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but 
> represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.
>
> To learn more about the reasoning behind this convention, please read [JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

In your case, your error is saying:

> invariant.js?409a
> :42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
> string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object.

From this error, we can infer that some Element type is invalid, and it may be do with class/functional components. At the top, in your imports, it looks like you're importing a component called `game`, but it may need to instead called `Game`. Without the capital letter, React is not reading this component as a component, but as an object type instead.

Try switching
`import game from "../component/game/game.jsx";`
to
`import Game from "../component/game/game.jsx";`
(and update the game.jsx file to export the capitalised name of the component).